# Address book change callback registered with ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback is never called (iOS 8)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8, abaddressbook

I've found plenty of examples around this but after reading the entire ABAddressBook documentation I'm still not able to figure out why, in my case, my change callback is not being called. I simply set up an address book and register a callback function for it.

I can access the address book just fine, but the callback function is never called no matter how much I change contacts in the Contacts app and then reopen my app. Is there any reason that the callback would never be called? I've already made sure I don't release the address book or unregister the callback.

The init code:

```
// Set up address book API.
CFErrorRef *error = NULL;
_addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, error);
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"Could not initialize address book: %@", CFBridgingRelease(CFErrorCopyFailureReason(*error)));
} else {
    ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback(_addressBook, RogerAddressBookChangeCallback, (__bridge void *)self);
    NSLog(@"Registered callback");
}
```

The callback function:

```
void RogerAddressBookChangeCallback(ABAddressBookRef addressBook, CFDictionaryRef info, void *context) {
    NSLog(@"Address book change");
    ABAddressBookRevert(addressBook);
    RogerAddressBook *instance = (__bridge RogerAddressBook *)context;
    [instance import];
}
```

I see the log output `Registered callback` but never `Address book change`.

Comment: Every time I change a contact's name in contact app, I see "Address book change" logged in the console, `ABAddressBookRef _addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, error);`, that's the only code I modified. Maybe the callback function is not in the same scope, I put the register code in `viewDidLoad`, and the callback function in the same view controller.

Comment: I have the same problem and I figured out that I should call ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback in main queue otherwise callback will not be called. Did you call it in main queue ?

Answer (score 1):

Actually the code for `ABAddressBook` is written in C. So you may find difficulties in using the Original ABAddressBook Framework.

So I suggest for using an third party library (Which is just an makeover of C to Obj-C) to access contacts and the Contacts Change.

Here is the link for an popular library https://github.com/Alterplay/APAddressBook

Using the above framework you could easily observe the changes in Address book.

**Observe address book external changes**

```
// start observing
[addressBook startObserveChangesWithCallback:^
{
    NSLog(@"Address book changed!");
}];
// stop observing
[addressBook stopObserveChanges];
```

This library also has lot of options like sorting, filtering etc.

Comment: I decided to go with my own direct solution because I needed very little, specific functionality out of the address book which APAddressBook didn't provide (such as linked contacts), and it had bugs in other areas (such as not calling `ABAddressBookRevert`). I have everything down and working very well and efficiently compared to APAddressBook, except for the callback being called so I'd like to just get that issue fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Access to address book requires user authorization. If authorization status is kABAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined, your code fails silently, returning non-nil result and producing no error.

I have next code to create address book:

```
- (ABAddressBookRef)newAddressBookRef
{
    ABAuthorizationStatus authorizationStatus = ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus();

    if (authorizationStatus == kABAuthorizationStatusAuthorized)
    {
        ABAddressBookRef addressBookRef = nil;

        CFErrorRef error;
        addressBookRef = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, &error);

        return addressBookRef;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

And next code to explicitly request address book access (usually performed on application start).

```
typedef void(^AddressBookHelperAccessRequestCompletionHandler)(BOOL accessGiven);

- (void)requestAccessToAddressBook:(ABAddressBookRef)addressBookRef withCompletionHandler:(AddressBookHelperAccessRequestCompletionHandler)completionHandler
{
    ABAuthorizationStatus authorizationStatus = ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus();

    switch (authorizationStatus)
    {
        case kABAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined:
        {
            // Request access permissions for even for NULL address book reference.
            // When permissions have not been granted yet, all address book references will be equal to NULL
            ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBookRef, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error)
            {
                if (granted)
                {
                    [self registerForAddressBookChanges];
                }

                if (completionHandler)
                {
                    completionHandler(granted);
                }
            });
            break;
        }
        case kABAuthorizationStatusDenied:
        case kABAuthorizationStatusRestricted:
            [self showNoContactsAccessAlert];
        default:
        {
            if (completionHandler)
            {
                completionHandler(authorizationStatus == kABAuthorizationStatusAuthorized);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```