# How to get Contact id Of Deleted Contacts from Address Book. Is it possible to know which contact is deleted?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want to know which specific contact has been deleted from Addressbook. 
I want to delete same contact from my app db too.
comparison of contacts is not what i am looking for.
i have not any idea if this is possible to fetch some?
Your feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can register for callback of change in **Address book**. When you get the notification for changes in address book, do update you db.

The code for ABAddressBook is written in C. So you may find difficulties in using the Original ABAddressBook Framework.

So I suggest for using an third party library *(Which is just an makeover of C to Obj-C)* to access contacts and the Contacts Change.

Here is the link for an popular library https://github.com/Alterplay/APAddressBook

Using the above framework you could easily observe the changes in Address book.

Observe address book external changes

```
// start observing
[addressBook startObserveChangesWithCallback:^
{
    NSLog(@"Address book changed!");
}];
// stop observing
[addressBook stopObserveChanges];
```

Via [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28921640/address-book-change-callback-registered-with-abaddressbookregisterexternalchange)